# How to interpret a Java thread dump?

Tags: java, thread-dump

I got a Java web-application here running on Tomcat6 with Ubuntu (server edition).
After 1-3 days, the application becomes very slow, so I created a threaddump after a fresh restart of tomcat and another one when the application starts to become slow:

Threaddump after fresh restart:

- via pkill -3: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/pkill-threaddump-fresh.out
- via jstack: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/jstack-threaddump-fresh.txt

Threaddump after 3 days (application is slow now):

- via pkill -3: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/pkill-threaddump.txt
- via jstack: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/jstack-threaddump.txt

From the dumps I posted, I can see that there are a lot of threads which do not seem to terminate for some reason. Unfortunately, I cannot tell which ones (class names?) and why. Using `top` on the console showed that the value for "VIRT" went up from ~800 (after fresh restart) to more than 4000 (after 3 days).

How can I interpret these dumps better? I already tried to load them into TDA but that didn't work (TDA doesn't seem to recognize them as dumps).

Maybe someone already sees in the dumps what's going on?

Comment: a thread dump might not contain enough information for tracking down responsiveness problems.

Comment: @MRalwasser What would be your suggestion?

Comment: I'm looking at it. I think it probably does contain enough information, but there are thousands of threads, so it will take some digging.

Comment: @valmar I would profile the application while it is suffering from  "slow responsiveness"

Comment: @MRalwasser How would you do that?

Comment: Using a profiler, like jprofiler, yourkit or jvisualvm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the jstack text file, I see numerous threads hanging in BCI (Byte-Code Interpreter), probably interpreting your code.
It does not seem to indicate where in your code it is interpreting.

It *does* say you have a deadlock condition.

In the .out file, I looked for what looks like application code. I see it hanging at

- EventProcessingThreadImpl.run:479 (2 threads)
- GC.java:100 (1 thread) in GC waiting for something to be released so that GC can proceed.
- Many threads parked in an unsafe condition, holding for a synchronizer, trying to read a job queue, in ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907
- I also see what looks like a lot of boilerplate - threads waiting to be given work to do, threads runnable, waiting for mail, etc.

Is this of any help?

**Added:**

OK, I searched for your code and found it on three threads, shown here, and beneath each one I've given a tentative explanation.

(Also, note [this link about using jstack to find deadlocks](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-Detect-Java-Thread-Deadlocks.html).)

```
----------------- 20607 -----------------
__pthread_cond_wait + 0xcc
_ZN13ObjectMonitor4waitElbP6Thread + 0x60a
_ZN18ObjectSynchronizer4waitE6HandlelP6Thread + 0x53
JVM_MonitorWait + 0x1e7
<Unknown compiled code>
* java.lang.Object.wait() bci:2 line:485 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.doSuspend0(java.lang.Object) bci:143 line:219 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.doSuspend(java.lang.Object) bci:7 line:185 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.wait(java.lang.Object) bci:198 line:1471 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.wait(java.lang.Object) bci:4 line:702 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Window.enterModal() bci:22 line:619 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Window.doModal() bci:67 line:551 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox.show(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, int,     org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener) bci:343 line:274 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox.show(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String) bci:6 line:128 (Interpreted frame)
* com.smampi.web.view.client.ClientController$5.onEvent(org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event) bci:8 line:417 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(org.zkoss.zk.ui.ext.Scope) bci:384 line:192 (Compiled frame)
????????
```

Thread 20607 is in com.smampi.web.view.client.ClientController$5.onEvent line 128 (I'm guessing).
It is displaying a modal message box and waiting for it to be answered.

```
----------------- 20878 -----------------
__pthread_cond_wait + 0xcc
_ZN13ObjectMonitor4waitElbP6Thread + 0x60a
_ZN18ObjectSynchronizer4waitE6HandlelP6Thread + 0x53
JVM_MonitorWait + 0x1e7
<Unknown compiled code>
* java.lang.Object.wait() bci:2 line:485 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.doSuspend0(java.lang.Object) bci:143 line:219 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.doSuspend(java.lang.Object) bci:7 line:185 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.wait(java.lang.Object) bci:198 line:1471 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.wait(java.lang.Object) bci:4 line:702 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Window.enterModal() bci:22 line:619 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Window.doModal() bci:67 line:551 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox.show(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, int, org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener) bci:343 line:274 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox.show(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String) bci:6 line:128 (Interpreted frame)
* com.smampi.web.view.client.ClientController$5.onEvent(org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event) bci:8 line:417 (Interpreted frame)
* org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(org.zkoss.zk.ui.ext.Scope) bci:384 line:192 (Compiled frame)
????????
```

Thread 20878 is also displaying a message box, but at line 417 (I'm guessing)

```
----------------- 22792 -----------------
__pthread_cond_wait + 0xcc
_ZN7Monitor5ILockEP6Thread + 0xb9
_ZN7Monitor4lockEP6Thread + 0xf2
_ZN7Monitor4lockEv + 0x28
_ZN18GenCollectorPolicy17mem_allocate_workEmbPb + 0xca
_ZN16GenCollectedHeap12mem_allocateEmbbPb + 0x38
_ZN13CollectedHeap26common_mem_allocate_noinitEmbP6Thread + 0x9a
_ZN13instanceKlass17allocate_instanceEP6Thread + 0x7d
_ZN18InterpreterRuntime4_newEP10JavaThreadP19constantPoolOopDesci + 0xda
* com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, java.lang.String) bci:378 line:413 (Interpreted frame)
* com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.startTLS(java.lang.String) bci:23 line:377 (Interpreted frame)
* com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.startTLS() bci:3 line:734 (Interpreted frame)
* com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) bci:24 line:676 (Interpreted frame)
* com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) bci:343 line:643 (Interpreted frame)
* javax.mail.Service.connect(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) bci:380 line:295 (Interpreted frame)
* com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer.connect() bci:427 line:514 (Interpreted frame)
* com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer$1.closed(javax.mail.event.ConnectionEvent) bci:10 line:593 (Interpreted frame)
* javax.mail.event.ConnectionEvent.dispatch(java.lang.Object) bci:55 line:96 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 22792 is trying to do a mail service connect from com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer.connect line 514, and that's being called from com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer$1.closed at line 593.
To do that, it looks like it's waiting for another thread to stop garbage collecting so it can allocate memory for a new thread so it can do a "startTLS" (for upgrading a plain text link to an encrypted one) so it can do a mail service connect.

Does that shed any light?

Comment: Mh, not really. I got no clue what `EventProcessingThreadImpl.run` could be and where it comes from. Also, I am clueless what those objects/threads are the GC is waiting for. I know that there a lot of threads parked waiting for something but for what? And which threads could that be? =/

Comment: @valmar: I was trying to figure out, of all the things on those stack traces, which were in your code, as opposed to Java system code or 3rd-party libraries. I'll take another look if you can give some clue as to which code is actually written as part of your application, because if there's anything you can fix, that's where it is.

Comment: My code comes from packages com.smampi.* - Everything else comes from other libraries and Java itself.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your effort, I really appreciate it! I find it a little confusing that a modal window is waiting (for what?). Usually, if a modal message box cannot be opened it simply should fail throwing an exception. Thread 22792 seems to be more interesting although I don't understand why the GC doesn't finish destroying objects.. How do you know that the thread is waiting for the GC anyway?

Comment: @valmar: You could find out what's causing the modal dialog box by looking at the line of code requesting it. That would be interesting because that might conceivably be hanging everything. The connect issue is it's waiting for a GC to complete, which could be waiting for something else to be unlocked by one of those other threads. (The file did say you had a deadlock.)

Comment: Hm, I think I already have a suspect. Thanks for your help, Mike. I think I can clear this on my own now.

Answer (score 0):

I see plenty of threads trying to establish an SSL context:

```
"JavaMail-EventQueue" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9f10416000 nid=0x54c6 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f9e3e92d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:255)
    - waiting to lock  (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$200(NativePRNG.java:108)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:97)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:433)
    - locked  (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:455)
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:189)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:82)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory.newAdapteeFactory(MailSSLSocketFactory.java:130)
    - locked  (a com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory)
    at com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory.(MailSSLSocketFactory.java:119)
    at com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory.(MailSSLSocketFactory.java:94)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:413)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.startTLS(Protocol.java:377)
    - locked  (a com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.startTLS(IMAPProtocol.java:734)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:676)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:643)
    - locked  (a com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    - locked  (a com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore)
    at com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer.connect(MailServer.java:514)
    at com.smampi.web.model.mail.server.MailServer$1.closed(MailServer.java:593)
    at javax.mail.event.ConnectionEvent.dispatch(ConnectionEvent.java:96)
    at javax.mail.EventQueue.run(EventQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've often seen servers become inexplicably slow during SSL setup (either as the server or as the client), when the amount of available entropy to the operating system becomes very low (i.e. the OS can't produce high-quality random numbers any more).

Try displaying the content of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` using

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

This should tell you how much random data the OS can provide at the moment, it should *usually* be at least in the hundereds. If it is consistently 0 or very close, then you've got a problem and need to introduce another source of entropy.

Then again it could also be the other way around: the *other* end of that connection might have problems gathering entropy and might be slow to answer.

Comment: I checked /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail and it gives me the value 130. I wonder if that would be enough? My application is a multi-user application where each user can set up multiple email accounts. Each account connects to its own, different email server via TLS or SSL (in a separate thread).

Comment: Good guess - but I can see only three threads in the native random number generation - two of them in a RUNNABLE state which indicates that no unnecessary waits are made. It's unlikely that this is the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got *lots* (thousands?) of Threads in the WAITING state. Read here about the various Thread States: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

This is a problem. You'll need to find why your app is creating so many Threads and not destroying them.

You've also *lots* of Threads called "JavaMail-EventQueue". Find out why the mailing life cycle is not completing. Adding some logging statements to your use of JavaMail, and you'll probably find some action regularly not completing.

Comment: Yes, I realized that there are a lot of threads in the waiting phase and I also suspected that my email logic has something to do with it. Unfortunately the application is very big and there are many classes that use JavaMail, so I don't really know how and where to start. Isn't there a way to find the name of the class which creates these threads (or the classname of the thread itself)?

Comment: No, there isn't a way I know of to find out what is creating the threads. If it is not in the Thread dump you are lost.

Try moving all your usage of JavaMail to a common class... like "JavaMailWrapper"...which simply logs then delegates to JavaMail. You'll have to do some painful work like this to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you accidentially try to talk TLS (encrypted) to a service which does not expect encrypted traffic so you have many threads waiting for a proper response which never come.

Are you  certain you use the correct port number for this service?